# Where can I find Gonthier's Coq code proving the four color theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, graph-theory, formal-proof, coq

In a 2008 article in the *Notices*, Georges Gonthier announced a computer-checked proof of the four color theorem using Coq:

> Gonthier, Georges.  Formal proof—the four-color theorem.
>   *Notices Amer. Math. Soc.* **55** (2008), no. 11, 1382–1393.  [PDF](http://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101382p.pdf)

Unfortunately, the article does not seem to provide a link to the Coq code.  Where can I find the code?  I'm not having any luck with Google.

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/5464e7b1-bd58-4f7c-bfe1-5d3b32d42e6d/default.aspx

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thanks, maybe that should be posted as an answer.  It's annoying that it's in a proprietary Microsoft packaging format, but given that Gonthier works for Microsoft I guess maybe I shouldn't be surprised...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is available on Microsoft's site: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/5464e7b1-bd58-4f7c-bfe1-5d3b32d42e6d/default.aspx .

Here is a [probably temporarily link](http://www72.zippyshare.com/v/28567991/file.html) to a hopefully complete extracted version in .7z format.

The proof depends on the ssreflect library, for which see http://www.msr-inria.fr/projects/mathematical-components-2/ (thankfully as two .tar.gz files).

**edit** as noted in the comments an updated, complete version can be obtained from https://github.com/math-comp/fourcolor

Comment: Thanks very much, darij.  I will try to build it on Linux, and if I succeed I'll post further details here.

Comment: @NateEldredge - I wonder what the license is on the code. Ideally it could be stored in an online version control repository of some kind, so that people could make use of it.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Each file says at the top `(c) Copyright Microsoft Corporation and Inria. All rights reserved.`  I didn't see any further license information.  But that makes it look like it's probably not allowed. :-(

Comment: @NateEldredge - hmph. :-( indeed.

Comment: You should ask Gonthier -- he and his team seem to usually release with the CeCILL licenses, so this might just be a minor technicality they didn't bother to clarify.

Comment: The Four Color library has been ported to Coq 8.x and is available at https://github.com/math-comp/fourcolor